# Issue in reading a firestore DB time stamp in an angular application and comparing

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection named Expenses with following which contains a field called DATE of type timestamp.

[image]

I am reading this in my Angular app to a class object Expense as below
Expense class

```
export class Expense {
  ID: string;
  DATE: Date;
  PERSON: string;
  EXP_TYPE: string;
  AMOUNT: number;
  DEBIT_ACCOUNT: string;
  DESCRIPTION: string;
  METER_READING: number;
  IS_MAINTANANCE: boolean;

  constructor(date, person, expType, amount, debitAcc, desc, meter, isMaintain) {
    this.DATE = date;
    this.PERSON = person;
    this.EXP_TYPE = expType;
    this.AMOUNT = amount;
    this.DEBIT_ACCOUNT = debitAcc;
    this.DESCRIPTION = desc;
    this.METER_READING = meter;
    this.IS_MAINTANANCE = isMaintain;
  }
}
```

The code used to Fetch Expenses from the collection using some filters is given below.
I am trying to compare the expense date with the dates provided by the arguments of the function below.
But it does not work. expense.DATE which is of Type Date does not support the functions like expense.DATE.toDateString. Please see code below. How Can I compare the date field in the firestore collection with the passed dates to the function

```
fetchExpenses(fromDate: Date, toDate: Date, person: Person, expType: ExpenseType) {
    this.expenses = [];
    this.db.collection('CLIENTS/DfyFUf9XLI73bNMs9XGZ/EXPENSES').snapshotChanges().pipe(map( docs => {
      return (
        docs.map(  doc => {
          const p = new Expense(doc.payload.doc.data()['DATE'], doc.payload.doc.data()['PERSON'], doc.payload.doc.data()['EXP_TYPE'],
            doc.payload.doc.data()['AMOUNT'], doc.payload.doc.data()['DEBIT_ACCOUNT'], doc.payload.doc.data()['DESCRIPTION'],
            doc.payload.doc.data()['METER_READING'], doc.payload.doc.data()['IS_MAINTANANCE']);
          p.ID = doc.payload.doc.id;
          // console.log(p.DATE.toDateString()); ==> This gives an error saying no function found as p.DATE.toDateString()
          return p;
        }).filter( expense => {
          let fromDateCriteriaMet = true;
          let toDateCriteriaMet = true;
          let personCriteriaMet = true;
          let expTypeCriteriaMet = true;
          if (fromDate != null) {
            console.log('expense.DATE = ' + expense.DATE);
            console.log('fromDate.toDateString() = ' + fromDate.toDateString());
            // the below line gives an error saying no function fund as expense.DATE.toDateString()
            if (expense.DATE.toDateString().localeCompare( fromDate.toDateString()) < 0) {
              console.log('fromDateCriteriaMet false')
              fromDateCriteriaMet = false;
            }
          }
          if (toDate != null) {
            console.log('expense.DATE = ' + expense.DATE);
            console.log('toDate.toDateString() = ' + toDate.toDateString());
            // the below line gives an error saying no function fund as expense.DATE.toDateString()
              if (expense.DATE.toDateString().localeCompare(toDate.toDateString()) > 0 ) {
              console.log('toDateCriteriaMet false')
              toDateCriteriaMet = false;
            }
          }
          if (person != null) {
            if (expense.PERSON != person.NAME) {
              personCriteriaMet = false;
            }
          }
          if (expType != null) {
            if (expense.EXP_TYPE != expType.TYPE) {
              expTypeCriteriaMet = false;
            }
          }
          return fromDateCriteriaMet && toDateCriteriaMet && personCriteriaMet && expTypeCriteriaMet;
        })
      );
    })).subscribe( (expenses: Expense[]) => {
      this.expenses = expenses;
      this.expenseChanges.next(this.expenses);
      console.log(this.expenses);
      });
  }
```

I get the below error

[image]

How can I compare the dates to implement this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore server timestamps are not actually of JavaScript Date type. Instead they give you an object like this

[image: Example firestore timestamp]

If you get the toDate() method, you can easily convert it to JavaScript Date object. But sometimes they only contain these:

```
{ seconds: number, nanoseconds: number }
```

In this case you need to convert the epoch time into your JavaScript Date object and then you can do other things.

You can do it like this:

```
new Date(expense.DATE.seconds * 1000);
```

And then you can convert it to date string like you want.